# Unable to alert response in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am a newbie at using jquery and stuffs so pardon me for my lack of explanation or for using the wrong terms.

Currently i have problems displaying my html as it shows a blank page. I tried to debug my php and it seems like there is no error there. When i tried typing the url on browser i can display this for example:

```
[{"vendorid":1,"vendor_name":"Korean stall","item_id":"1","item_name":"kimchi fried rice","item_image":kimchi fried rice.jpg,"item_description":aromatic fried rice,"price":"3.00","available":"Yes"}]
```

The vendorid is taken from the image in the previous page by appending to the table using this code:

```
<a href='#' class='ui-img' onClick='window.location=&quot;shop.html?vendorid=" + arr[i].vendorid + "&quot;'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "' height='150'>
```

In javascript, i am able to alert(url) and get the vendorid. But i can't alert out the array in alert(response) as nothing comes out. However, when i tried the onclick="shop()"; without getting any vendorid, my alert(url) displays vendorid=undefined, followed on by the second alert, alert=[].

This is my javascript:

```
    function getShopDetails() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = serverURL() + "/shop.php";
            url += "?vendorid=" + decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["vendorid"]);

            **alert(url);**
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                     displayShopDetails(xmlhttp.responseText);
                 }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();     
    }

    function displayShopDetails(response){
        var arr = JSON.parse(**response**);
        **alert(response);**
        var i;

        $(**"#mybody"**).find("tr").remove();
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        $(**"#mybody"**).append( 
            "<tr><td>" + arr[i].vendorID + 
            "</td><td>" + arr[i].vendor_name +
            "</td><td>" + arr[i].itemname +
            "</td><td>" + arr[i].price +
            "</td><td>" + arr[i].item_description + "</td></tr>"
        );

        }

        $(**"#itemtable"**).table("refresh");
   }

    getShopDetails();
```

This is my html to display the table:

```
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id=**"itemtable"**> 
        <table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive" id="homey">
            <tbody id=**"mybody"**>
            </tbody>
        </table>            
    </div>
```

Not sure if this is needed.. but this is my php:

```
    <?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 

    $conn = new mysqli(XXXXX);
    $vendorid = $_GET['vendorid']; 
    $result = $conn->query("select * from menu where vendorid = '" . $vendorid . "'");

    $outp = "["; 
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {  
        if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}  
        $outp .= '{"vendorid":'  . $rs["vendorid"] . ',';  
        $outp .= '"vendor_name":"' . $rs["vendor_name"] . '",';  
        $outp .= '"item_id":"' . $rs["item_id"] . '",';  
        $outp .= '"item_name":"' . $rs["item_name"] . '",';  
        $outp .= '"item_image":' . $rs["item_image"] . ',';  
        $outp .= '"item_description":' . $rs["item_description"] . ',';  
        $outp .= '"price":"' . $rs["price"] . '",';  
        $outp .= '"available":"' . $rs["available"] . '"}'; } 

    $outp .="]"; 
    $conn->close(); 
    echo($outp); 
    ?>
```

Does anyone knows why can't i alert out the array in alert(response)? Sorry for the lengthy post. :((

Comment: any errors in the browser console? also, doesn't PHP have methods to create properly formatted JSON for you rather than you having to hand roll JSON? if any of those string values (description, name etc) have a `"` in them, you'll have issues rolling by hand

Comment: Ahh, there's the problem ... it's so obvious when you look at the sample output ... you need `"` around the VALUE of item_image and item_description - just like you do with the other strings in the output (see what I mean about hand rolled JSON)

Comment: This code is a perfect example of how to create a vulnerable shop system. Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks for the tip! Will definitely read up on sql injection. I'm actually doing this shop system on a school based project and have very limited knowledge on coding and the system's vulnerabilities. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I thought that this would become part of a real-world shop system... it's totally ok for learning purposes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the syntax highlighting for the data you output

```
[{
    "vendorid":1,
    "vendor_name":"Korean stall",
    "item_id":"1",
    "item_name":"kimchi fried rice",
    "item_image":kimchi fried rice.jpg,
    "item_description":aromatic fried rice,
    "price":"3.00",
    "available":"Yes"
}]
```

You should immediately see the problem

```
    "item_image":kimchi fried rice.jpg,
    "item_description":aromatic fried rice,
```

No `"` around those to values

Comment: Her only mistake is the `$outp .= '{"vendorid":'  . $rs["vendorid"] . ','; `  should be `outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  .outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  .outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  . rs["vendorid"] . '",';`

Comment: omg thanks!! i didn't know a simple quotation mark in my php will make this difference. I just assumed that since my php can return the output, everything will work. May i know what do you mean by using properly formatted JSON? Since my school uses the hand rolled method, I just followed their method.

Comment: Should be `outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  .outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  .outp .= '{"vendorid":"'  . rs["vendorid"] . '",';` <---- somehow it keeps printing twice, it's just the formatting is messing my comment. Btw, @yanxifoo, you should click 'accept' to his answer to appreciate him.

Comment: `properly formatted JSON?` - well, JSON has a "syntax", which your code didn't properly apply, which is why the JSON.parse would fail ... I just made a passing comment about PHP, I wondered if it actually does have some `JSON.stringify` type method to make this easier - it's not important, if you have to do hand rolled JSON, then it's not a problem - but now you know what to look for :p

Comment: Thanks all for helping out with my question! @JaromandaX will definitely not make the same mistake again. Have a good day! :)

Comment: @yanxifoo - I'm not being disrespectful, but you probably will - that nest of `'` and `"` is a nightmare and will trip you up again :p happens to the best of us